# Ethernet shield connected to local network, not to internet

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet

Using the WebServer example file I have been able to confirm that my arduino is connected to my local network and I can open the page in my browser. However any attempt at contacting addresses outside my own network fails. For example this simple script:

```c
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <Ethernet.h>

    EthernetClient client;

    byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
    IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 25);
    IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);
    IPAddress dns(8, 8, 8, 8);
    byte server[] = { 64, 233, 187, 99 }; // Google

    void setup() {  
      Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, dns, gateway);
      Serial.begin(9600);
      delay(1000);
      Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
    }

    void loop() {
      if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
        Serial.println("connected");
        client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.0");
        client.println();
      } else {
        Serial.println("connection failed");
      }
    }
```

This consistently returns `connection failed`. The ethernet cable in the arduino has an active internet connection, albeit via a switch. My board is an arduino uno.

Answer (score 1):

Find a server that doesn't automatically switch modes to https as google does.  If you put 64.233.187.99/search?q=arduino%20HTTP/1.0   in your browser you'll see that it switches to https.

If make the same request via the wget terminal app it fails.

```
--2020-01-17 11:42:26--  http://64.233.187.99/search?q=arduino%20HTTP/1.0
Connecting to 64.233.187.99:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/search?q=arduino%20HTTP/1.0 [following]
--2020-01-17 11:42:26--  http://www.google.com/search?q=arduino%20HTTP/1.0
Resolving www.google.com... 172.217.4.132, 2607:f8b0:4007:80c::2004
Connecting to www.google.com|172.217.4.132|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2020-01-17 11:42:28 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

There should also be an error returned to the client object which you can print out for debugging the conection.

Change your code to print out the return value of the client.connect call like so

```
void loop() {
      int result = client.connect(server, 80); 
      if (x) {
        Serial.println("connected");
        client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.0");
        client.println();
      } else {
        Serial.println("connection failed");
        Serial.println(x);  // print out the error
      }
    }
```

One last thing, you set your dns server to 8.8.8.8 which should generally be set to your gateway / router of 192.168.1.1.